# JS/CSS 3dtransform constant movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to use the wheel script I found here: http://codepen.io/Aldlevine/pen/yGLqd and add something to allow it to be always slowly rotating until it's hovered/clicked. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

```
$( '.wheel > div' ).each( function( i ) {
                var angle = -( coords.y / 2 ) + ( 360 / 10 ) * i;
                $( this ).css( 'transform', 'perspective(3000px) rotate3d(1,0,0,' + angle + 'deg) translate3d(0,0,75px)' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the [transitionend-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) and restart the animation once that happens. This will make it run "forever". As soon as you notice a :hover, you can stop the ongoing transition.

Take a look [over here](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/) for a reference how to better control the CSS3 transitions.

Comment: But the animation would have to start for the event to happen. It doesnt do anything currently until interacted with. What to call to make it start spinning is where I'm most confused.

Comment: Then listen for the document to have loaded, then start the animation at that point. Take a look at the window loaded event.

Comment: I know it would be run on pageload, what I'm asking is what command/function would I run?? Since the existing onchange function loops thru each div and sets a css transform on each, would I have to basically duplicate that into an onload?

Comment: Since the existing code uses #s from the mousewheel or drag operation, i dont understand the best way to set an initial arbitrary rotation & speed.